# Idea: techmology.stackexchange.com

Tags: discussion, feature-request, scope, site-proposal

This might not sound like a good idea to many of you. Also I do not want to criticise the rest of on-topic sites and the community.

Off late, it has become increasingly difficult to find a Stack Exchange site which has an interest in answering your question. It is not easy to choose from a variety of Stack Exchange sites and decide where exactly to ask the question. Here is my idea:

1. Have a site called techmology.stackexchange.com. (Ali G reference. http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=techmology)
2. The FAQ should say ask any question related to programming. Really anything. No offence will be taken for the stupidest of questions. it can be open ended etc. It is like a regular tech forum with all stackoverflow features.
3. In case a question qualifies as a non-off-topic question on one of the other sites, such as stackoverflow, serverfault, etc, it will get migrated there.
4. The site is not meant for future references to other people. It is meant for people who need help now. And for people who care less about what the site rules are and more about helping other people.
5. Downvoting and user banning if only the question is not related to technology in anyway.
6. Any question marked as off topic on any of the other techmology sites get migrated here.

This would make it much easier for people like me who need help.

What happens currently is that the moment I ask a question, I get downvoted. The question has to conform to a very strict set of rules.

IMHO, Internet is meant to be for free people according to me and conformism surely leads to decline. Let us start a stackoverflow site which is free again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> 4. The site is not meant for future references to other people. It is meant for people who need help now. And for people who care less about what the site rules are and more about helping other people.

That's not what we, at Stack Exchange are interested in creating. We are looking to create resources that will be used for the long term.

> The question has to conform to a very strict set of rules.

Yes. This keeps high quality posts here and keeps experts around - you know, the people who actually answer your questions with something that will be correct and helpful. Not doing so would drive them away.

Comment: I am not saying we should  change the behaviour of rest of the sites. Let them be the way they are. Is it not possible have a single exception Stack Exchange site. We do not need experts to even come there unless they want to. I am sure people would be interested in helping people who are not very good at asking questions, but have a legitimate question

Comment: @shortfellow - my point is. We, at Stack Exchange, are not interested in creating such sites.

Comment: Okay then. Good luck.

Comment: @shortfellow - we tried. They failed. Badly.

Comment: You tried? Can you give me an example?

Comment: @shortfellow I think Oded means http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ in the beginning, before it went through a major change.

Comment: @shortfellow - http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/5654/are-you-still-confused-about-what-programmers-is-for

Comment: Fair enough.  I accept your answer

Comment: @shortfellow - probably a better link: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3412/what-is-the-history-behind-the-site-scope-change-from-npr-to-conceptual-questio

Comment: @Oded Really appreciate you answering my stupid questions. :D You have done it so many times.

Answer (score 1):

As long as askers rely on people to answer their questions without pay, they are going to have to cater to the preferences of the people who can answer. Otherwise, the people who can answer will give their free time to someone else who *does* cater to their preferences. Or, they'll stop giving away their free time altogether.

If what the askers want is someone who is going to *cater to the preferences of the asker above all*, then it's called "hiring a consultant".